# Calculating distance on riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

The length $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow M$ are defined by integrating their tangent vectors along $\gamma$ a Riemannian manifold.

$l_{\gamma} := \int_{a}^{b} |\gamma^{'}|dt$

Now I have the question that it's said that the tangent at a point is not unique, then how is this integration well defined or computed.

Now I may be confusing between that there is no unique tangent at a point in manifold Vs tangent of curves.
Maybe curves have unique tangents depending on the parameterization, but more clarity be helpful.

Comment: The short answer is that the tangent vector is unique and well-defined. To get a more informative answer, you have to elaborate more.

Comment: You are confusing the uniqueness of tangent vectors with the uniqueness of curves. A given tangent vector at a point is unique. Now, the infinite number of curves which share the property of being determined by that unique vector at that unique point form an equivalence class which is isomorphic to the set of derivations on smooth functions at the given point.

Comment: I find it very difficult to understand what you are trying to say. You should try to learn the subject more systematically by reading a textbook. There are many textbooks on differential geometry to choose from.

Comment: @Volk The tangent vector is derived from the curve, so you are saying that even for different curves, at a point the tangent vector for a manifold is unique?

Comment: @BhartenduKumar Think of it this way... I am driving in a car and turn left going 10mph on a certain road and then continue straight. Another car behind me turns left going 10mph on the very same road and then turns right. We have taken different paths globally but locally, at some point where we turned left, our velocities were identical. There is only one possible way to be headed directly East at exactly 10mph at a specific point on Earth's surface regardless of the overall path you take.